# javascript, if current url withour request part

Tags: javascript

I want do something: if something type url address like: `www.mydomain.com/search`(without request part), I want do something with javascript, fill with the url like `www.mydomain.com/search?search=car`, but nothing happened in my code.

```
   <script>
    var curent_url = document.URL;
    if(document.URL.indexOf("?") < 0){ //if(!document.URL.match(/\?/)){
        //alert('ok');
        document.URL = curent_url+'?search=car';
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `document.URL`, check for an empty `document.location.search`:

```
if (document.location.search.length === 0) {
  // empty query string... append your part to doc
  document.location.href = document.location.href + "?search=car";
}
```

Examine the `document.location` object in your console to see what else it offers.  There's usually no need to parse out `document.URL` or `document.location.href` directly.

```
console.dir(document.location);
```